# Heroku lightning:lint path

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, heroku

I am going through [Salesforce Lightning CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_usage.htm)
When I am trying to run it on a contorller.js file which is present in the local system `(C:\Users\arpit.sethi\Desktop\bankAccount_EditController.js)`. I am using following command:-

```
heroku lightning:lint C:/Users/arpit.sethi/Desktop/bankAccount_EditController.js
```

but I am getting below error, can anyone please help me.

> 'Search for "**/*.js" in folder
>   "C:/Users/arpit.sethi/Desktop/bankAccount_EditController.js"' ' ->
>   Ignoring:
>   **/node_modules/**,**/jsdoc/**,**/htdocs/**,**/invalidTest/**,**/purposelyInvalid/**,**/invalidTestData/**,**/validationTest/**,**/lintTest/**,**/target/**,**/parseError/**,**/*.junk.js,***/_mock?.js'
>   C:\Users\arpit.sethi\AppData\Local\heroku\plugins\node_modules\glob\sync.js:327
>           throw error
>           ^
>
> Error: ENOTDIR invalid cwd
>   C:\Users\arpit.sethi\Desktop\bankAccount_EditController.js
>       at GlobSync._readdirError (C:\Users\arpit.sethi\AppData\Local\heroku\plugins\node_modules\glob\sync.js:324:21)
>       at GlobSync._readdir (C:\Users\arpit.sethi\AppData\Local\heroku\plugins\node_modules\glob\sync.js:290:10)
>       at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\Users\arpit.sethi\AppData\Local\heroku\plugins\node_modules\glob\sync.js:350:22)
>       at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\arpit.sethi\AppData\Local\heroku\plugins\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
>       at new GlobSync (C:\Users\arpit.sethi\AppData\Local\heroku\plugins\node_modules\glob\sync.js:48:10)
>       at Function.globSync [as sync] (C:\Users\arpit.sethi\AppData\Local\heroku\plugins\node_modules\glob\sync.js:26:10)
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\arpit.sethi\AppData\Local\heroku\plugins\node_modules\salesforce-lightning-cli\lib\linter.js:154:24)
>       at Object.run (C:\Users\arpit.sethi\AppData\Local\heroku\plugins\node_modules\salesforce-lightning-cli\commands\lint.js:66:26)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\arpit.sethi\AppData\Local\heroku\tmp\heroku-script-014850679:20:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, it is trying to search the `.js` file in `C:/Users/arpit.sethi/Desktop/bankAccount_EditController.js`. It is considering `bankAccount_EditController.js` as a folder.

**Workaround**: Create a new folder and add the `bankAccount_EditController.js` in that folder and then give the path of the created folder.

```
heroku lightning:lint C:/Users/arpit.sethi/Desktop/FolderName
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want To run CLI on a specific file then use

```
heroku lightning:lint C:/Users/arpit.sethi/Desktop/FolderName --files bankAccount_EditController.js
```

Reference :- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_usage.htm